# Routing of a new component and with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component and it calls an API, if the API returns a certain result it should refer to the /welcome page (it is the Welcome.js). For this I would like to pass the email. Is there an option how I can redirect to the other component and pass the props email at the same time?

```
const handleLogin = () => {
        axios.post('localhost:3000:/login', {"email":email, "password":password})
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            console.log(res.status);
            if(res.status === 200) {
              setValidationWrong(true);
             // Forward to another component and pass on the email
             // <Link to="/welcome"> </Link> 
              
              
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            setValidationWrong(false);
        })
      };
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Testchat from "../components/Testchat";

const Welcome = (props) => {

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome{props.email}</h1>
        <Testchat></Testchat>
    </div>
);
}

export default Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. When you use the history API, you can send a location instead of a string.

e.g.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

```
const location = {
  pathname: '/welcome',
  state: { email: foo@baz.com }
};

history.push(location);
```

Same thing is valid for the Link component:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/welcome",
    state: { email: foo@baz.com }
  }}
/>
```

And in the Welcome component you access it like through `props.location.state.email`.